# Splitting a data set into thirds using multiple criteria in different columns

Tags: sql

I have a data set that is to be split into thirds using the following rules:

1. Rank first by an Open_Rate column (where highest Open_Rate should return)
2. In the case that open rates are equal, rank by the last open rate
3. In the case that there is no last open rate, use the signup to determine the ranking.

Here is an example of how the ranking should look:

Bob 100% open

Bill 50% open, last open 7/31

Connie 50% open, last open 6/29

Dan 0% open, signed up 8/1

Eddie 0% open, signed up 7/15

The data set should then be split into thirds--an upper third, a middle third, and a lower third.

My problem comes with splitting the data set into thirds. I have this query to select the top 33 percent and populate a new table, but I'm not sure how to select the "middle" 33 percent by the same criteria and "lower" 34 percent.

```
select top 33 percent 
*

from Sends_And_Opens_BySubscriber

order by 
Open_Percentage desc, Last_Open_Date desc, SignUp_Date desc
```

Comment: Data as a table would really help, as would desired results.  Also, tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a "third" using `ntile()`:

```
select sos.*,
       ntile(3) over (order by Open_Percentage desc, Last_Open_Date desc, SignUp_Date desc) as grouping
from Sends_And_Opens_BySubscriber sos;
```